# Developing a new app: Is there a way to share the app with my remote Client so he can beta test the app on his iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, developer-program, swift

I'm developing a simple iPhone app (using Xcode & SwiftUI) for a Client who is in another state (here in the US).

I have a valid up-to-date developer account.

I'd like to release the app to his iPhone so he can beta-test the app.
Is this possible?

Is there any way to deploy the app to his iPhone even though he is geographically distant (and cannot connect his iPhone to my development Mac)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to try using TestFlight  for this if at all possible.

- https://testflight.apple.com/

It’s very fully featured and has good support for very large teams. As long as you have something that can meet the basic review, it meets and exceeds your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much.  That is exactly what I needed. 